# How to make pytorch lightning module have injected, nested models?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, transfer-learning, pytorch-lightning

I have some nets, such as the following (augmented) resnet18:

```
num_classes = 10
resnet = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
for param in resnet.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = True
num_ftrs = resnet.fc.in_features
resnet.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)
```

And I want to use them inside a lightning module, and have it handle all optimizations, to_device, stages and so on. In other words, I want to register those modules for my lightning module.
I also want to be able to access their public members.

```
class MyLightning(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, resnet):
        super().__init__()
        self._resnet = resnet
        self._criterion = lambda x: 1.0

    def forward(self, x):
        resnet_out = self._resnet(x)
        
        loss =  self._criterion(resnet_out)
        return loss


my_lightning = MyLightning(resnet)
```

The above doesn't optimize any parameters.

Trying

```
def __init__(self, resnet)
    ...
    _layers = list(resnet.children())[:-1]
    self._resnet = nn.Sequential(*_layers)
```

Doesn't take `resnet.fc` into account. This also doesn't make sense to be the intended way of nesting models inside pytorch lightning.

---

How to nest models in pytorch lightning, and have them fully accessible and handled by the framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The training loop and optimization process is handles by the [`Trainer`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_lightning.trainer.trainer.Trainer.html?highlight=trainer) class. You can do so by initializing a new instance:

```
>>> trainer = Trainer()
```

And wrapping your PyTorch Lightning module with it. This way you can perform [fitting](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_lightning.trainer.trainer.Trainer.html#pytorch_lightning.trainer.trainer.Trainer.fit), [tuning](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_lightning.trainer.trainer.Trainer.html#pytorch_lightning.trainer.trainer.Trainer.tune), [validating](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_lightning.trainer.trainer.Trainer.html#pytorch_lightning.trainer.trainer.Trainer.validate), and [testing](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_lightning.trainer.trainer.Trainer.html#pytorch_lightning.trainer.trainer.Trainer.test) on that instance provided a [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) or [`LightningDataModule`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/datamodules.html?highlight=datamodule):

```
>>> trainer.fit(my_lightning, train_dataloader, val_dataloader)
```

---

You will have to implement the following functions on your Lightning module (*i.e.* in your case `MyLightning`):

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `init` | Define computations here |
| `forward` | Use for inference only (separate from `training_step`) |
| `training_step` | the complete training loop |
| `validation_step` | the complete validation loop |
| `test_step` | the complete test loop |
| `predict_step` | the complete prediction loop |
| `configure_optimizers` | define optimizers and LR schedulers |

*source [`LightningModule`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/lightning_module.html) documentation page.*

Keep in mind a `LightningModule` ***is*** a `nn.Module`, so whenever you define a `nn.Module` as attribute to a `LightningModule` in the `__init__` function, this module will end being registered as a sub-module to the parent pytorch lightning module.

Answer (score -2):

The pytorch model should inherit from ***nn.Module***, So you should find firstly the resnet18 in pytorch, then you can use the resnet18 or revise it by youself

The origin resnet codes is in this path: ...\python\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\resnet.py, you import the resnet network from here, so you can use it directly.

Now, you will find the original codes

> class ResNet(nn.Module):...

https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/resnet.py#L166

And import it like

> from torchvision.models import ResNet

Finally, you can inherit from ResNet

> class MyLightning(ResNet):